# The code running in spyder gives a KeyError: not found in axis' on the server

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run the code below with spyder on my windows computer, I don't get any errors.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="a.json"
url ="myurl"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
'X-ApiKey': 'my_api_key'}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
a=req.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(a['data'])



dffinal=pd.DataFrame()
ids=df.id.to_list()
for i in ids:
    url ="myurl"+i
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
    'X-ApiKey': 'my_api_key'}
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    a=req.json()
    a = pd.json_normalize(a['data'])
    dffinal=dffinal.append(a)

dffinal=dffinal.drop(['contentModules','audience.customerSegmentInline.matching',
        'audience.customerSegmentInline.criteria', 'audience.lists',
        'audience.customerSegmentKind', 'audience.customerSegmentId'],axis=1)


def to_gbq():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = client.dataset('aa')    
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
                dffinal, 'aa.bb', job_config=job_config
    )
    print("Starting job {}".format(load_job))
    return ("Done!", 200)
to_gbq()
```

However, when I run the command on the server `python3 filename.py` , I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "['contentModules' 'audience.customerSegmentInline.matching'\n 'audience.customerSegmentInline.criteria' 'audience.lists'\n 'audience.customerSegmentKind' 'audience.customerSegmentId'] not found in axis"
```

also i tried this:

`dffinal=dffinal.drop([5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=1)`

but i get the same error:

`KeyError "[5 6 7 8 9 10] not found in axis"`

Some additional info: python version on my windows computer: **3.8.8**, python version is **3.6.8** on server with centos 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python version installed on the server was 3.6.8. I upgraded this version to python 3.8.12 and the problem was solved.